# setInterval can't access variable?

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript function named `showchild(pgid)`. I have called function on document ready...

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
     var pgid = $('#hiddenuserkey').val();
    //alert(pgid);
     showchild(pgid);
     setInterval("showchild(pgid)",1000);
});
```

Comment: It's because `pgid` is *local* to the `ready` handler, but the string `"showchild(pgid)"` is evaluated in *global* scope. *That's why* you should not pass a string to `setXXXXXX`.

Comment: That's an answer, not a comment. ;)

Comment: -1 For "not working". Please make sure to include appropriate diagnostic information (in the future).

Answer (score 7):

You are using it in the worst possible way - passing a string.

Use the following code instead:

```
setInterval(function() {
    showchild(pgid);
}, 1000);
```

When passing a string, it will be evaluated in the global context without having access to any non-global variables. By passing a function (the preferred way) all accessible variables are preserved in the function's closure so `pgid` is defined inside that function when it's called.